# Adding AdMob from Firebase with Segmentation fault:11 error

Tags: ios, firebase, segmentation-fault, admob, swift3

There is a question about `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`, but no answer applies to my situation.

I am using Swift3, Xcode 8.0 to add AdMob with Firebase and got this error:

Error:

```
1.  While loading members for 'CategoryVC' at <invalid loc>
2.  While deserializing decl #92 (PATTERN_BINDING_DECL)
3.  While deserializing decl #3 (VAR_DECL)

Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
 }

}



 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import GoogleMobileAds

  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx")

    return true

    }
 }
```

Comment: Try deleting your derived data and then build it.

Comment: Thanks, Dravidian. Do you mean to clean it? I have done this.

Comment: No deleting your derived data, Search how to..

Comment: Hi Dravidian, I figured out and deleted derived data. It only works well for one ViewController. When I added the same code to multiple ViewControllers, the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! All problems happened after installing `Firebase/Admob` and adding `bannerView` code. The `CategoryVC` mentioned in #1 is the only `ViewController` I added `bannerView`. Because when I installed `pod file` using `terminal`, it mentioned my `Cocoapods` is not up-to-date. So I updated `Cocoapods` to see any good luck.

Steps:

1. Open your terminal. Input:

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```
2. Navigate to your project folder and open your pod file. Make changed if necessary, or just save and exit.
3. Run:

   ```
   pod update
   ```

It may not apply to your situation. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code in **viewDidLoad()** to :-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let request                     = GADRequest()
    bannerView.alpha              = 1
    bannerView.adSize             = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape
    bannerView.delegate           = self
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    request.testDevices             = [kGADSimulatorID]
    bannerView.adUnitID           = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.load(request)

 }
```

Also make sure you have declared the custom class of that *bannerView* in your storyboard as `GADBannerView` too.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the example project provided by Google AdMob, The fix was to add the line use_frameworks! to the pod file dependency list.

After that, the app required less imports to run and hasn't failed to build since.